# How to get private ip of EC2 instances spin up by ASG using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have tried following code in order to obtain ip's from ASG, which has been  created using Terraform? Is this a good practice or a bad one? But i got the correct ouput as i expected.

```
data "aws_instances" "test" {
instance_tags {
Environment = "${var.environment}",
instance    = "${var.db_instance_name}"
}

instance_state_names = ["running"]


depends_on = ["aws_sqs_queue.ansible", "aws_autoscaling_group.sample"]
}
```

output.tf

```
output "privateips" {
  value = "${data.aws_instances.test.private_ips}"
}
```

Comment: You should explain why you think you need it but in general it's a bad idea. Instances in an ASG should be as configured as much as possible by the AMI with environmental specific stuff done in user data.

Comment: The reason it's usually a bad idea, is because if you spin up instances using an ASG, you don't have (or want to have) control over the specific instances. They could be any number of instances, and could shut down / launch at any point in time (e.g. a self-healing, autoscaling architecture), as such, knowing anything about specific instances defeats the purpose of an ASG and you might as well spin up some persistent instances. The problem being: You may use Terraform to manipulate the instances, but you'd need to apply Terraform after each capacity change within the ASG.

Comment: Yes, It will apply terraform when there is a issue, Actually i'm builiding a platform.

Comment: Use case for needing ASG-spawned ec2 instance private IPs:  A rails app with db migrations that need to be executed against the database.  The migration has to occur on an instance with access to the database (like an app server) with rails installed.  A bastion host should not have access to the database, but can be used as a jump box to any running app instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating the ASG, add a local provisioner at the end to execute a local script that interacts with AWS using the cli, so that you can query the ASG IPs:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "artifactory" {
  name_prefix          = "${var.env}-Application-ASG-"
  vpc_zone_identifier  = ["${var.app_subnets}"]
  max_size             = "${var.asg_max}"
  min_size             = "${var.asg_min}"
  desired_capacity     = "${var.asg_desired}"
  force_delete         = true
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.application.name}"
  target_group_arns    = ["${aws_alb_target_group.application.arn}"]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./getips.sh"
  }
}
```

script:

```
ips=""
ids=""
while [ "$ids" = "" ]; do
  ids=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-names $ASG --region $REGION --query AutoScalingGroups[].Instances[].InstanceId --output text)
  sleep 1
done
for ID in $ids;
do
    IP=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $ID --region $REGION --query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress --output text)
    ips="$ips,$IP"
done
```

Comment: This is kind of helping in my case.

Comment: Hi @victor-m, thanks for sharing. Do you know how to retrieve the output of the script?

Comment: You could redirect the output into a file or you can save it into the AWS Parameter Store, and then retrieve it using terraform.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IPs of the instances in a JSON structure with a single AWS command line execution:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
--filters Name=tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName,Values=$ASG \
--query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{"private_ip":PrivateIpAddress}' \
--output json
```

Sample output:

```
[
    [
        {
            "private_ip": "10.24.2.120"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "private_ip": "10.24.1.147"
        }
    ]
]
```

This script takes advantage of the fact that an autoscaling group adds a tag to each instance it launches, where the value of that tag is the name of the ASG.

You can place this code directly in the ASG resource definition using the local exec trick presented by @victorm:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs" {
    name = var.asg_name

    ...

    provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = "aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName,Values=${var.asg_name} --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{private_ip:PrivateIpAddress}' --output json"
    }
}
```

I added this code to one of my own deployments to make sure it worked.  It remains to be worked out how you'd grab and use the output of the execution.  I was doing something slightly different with this code.  I created an `output` that spits out the command without executing it.  Then I just copy/paste it into my terminal window to run it.  I haven't found the need to fully automate the process, without that one manual step.  I use that trick (outputting a shell command that can be copy/pasted and executed) for a number of things.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data resource as such and output the private or public IPs

```
data "aws_instances" "web_instances" {
  instance_state_names = ["running"]
}

output "instance_state_privip" {
  description = "Instance Private IPs"
  value = data.aws_instances.web_instances.private_ips
}

output "instance_state_pubip" {
  description = "Instance Public IPs"
  value = data.aws_instances.web_instances.public_ips
}
```